# How to Autofill values dynamically from a list to a range of cells in an Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Hi I have a list mentioned below. I want the values in the list to be filled in excel row wise which starts from the cell "A12".

```
                    List<string> fmlist = new List<string>();
                    fmlist = gateways.Keys.Select(x => x.FirmwareVersion).Distinct().ToList();
```

Please find the Snapshot for the output reference. 
[image]

Below is what I have tried, but it fills in the last value to the row 12 to the excel.

```
                    foreach (var item in fmlist)
                    {
                        for (int index = 12; fmlist.Contains(item);)
                        {
                            sheet.Cells[index, 1].Value = item;
                            index++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 12;
foreach (var item in fmlist)
{
    if (fmlist.Contains(item))
    {
        sheet.Cells[index, 1].Value = item;
        index++;
    }
}
```

This worked for me!

Comment: the `if` statement is redundant. You're already looping through `fmlist` so obviously the `item` will be in it.

Comment: Yes, removing if statement also will work!